# How to find two specific requrement in json response

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
async getAllEmpLeavesCount(orgId) {
    let data=[];
    let fullInfo=[];
    return await sequelize
      .query(`CALL getAllEmpLeaves(?)`, {
        replacements: [orgId],
      })
      .then((res) => {
        for(let i=0;i<res.length;i++){
          data[i]=res[i].employees_id;
        
        }
        const resultArr = data.reduce((acc,item)=>{ if(!acc.includes(item)){ acc.push(item); } return acc; },[])
       

        let dataset={
          employees_id:'',
          employees_name:'',
          Annual:0,
          Medical:0,
          Casual:0,
          lieu:0,
          
        }
        for(let i=0;i<resultArr.length;i++){
            dataset.employees_id=resultArr[i],
            dataset.employees_name=res.find(o => o.employees_id===resultArr[i]).name_w_initials,
            **dataset.Annual=res.find(o => (o.employees_id===resultArr[i]) && (o.leaves_type==="Annual")).days**
            // here is the problem

            fullInfo.push(JSON.stringify(dataset));
        }
        
        return fullInfo;
      })
  }
```

I got the error can not read days property, but there is a property days I think filtration is wrong which i used res.find(o => (o.employees_id===resultArr[i]) && (o.leaves_type==="Annual"))

Comment: not quite understand what it is you are trying to do.. maybe give a better input explanation and desired output

Comment: i add the full code

Comment: hmm.. what comes out it you console.log(res); do you have res.days? because that is what your code trying to do.. find the days property on res object.. therefore res.days

Comment: res output like that
    {
        "employees_id": 22293,
        "leaves_type": "Medical",
        "days": 4.5,
        "employee_id": 22293,
        "name_w_initials": "R.Rathnayaka"
    },
    {
        "employees_id": 22293,
        "leaves_type": "Casual",
        "days": 1,
        "employee_id": 22293,
        "name_w_initials": "R.Rathnayaka"
    },

Comment: ok.. then is employees_id always in line with i? say first employee will have employee_id === 1 and second employee will have employee_id === 2? because that is the first part of your .find()

Comment: ` dataset.employees_name=res.find(o => o.employees_id===resultArr[i]).name_w_initials,` this is working i can get employee name

Comment: true.. then I think for the employee[i] he/she does not have leaves_type === "Annual".. say from your res output above, employees_id: 22293 only have "medical" and "casual", but not "annual"

Comment: no Anual also here if i remove one conditions it is working but wrong data ,if i put two conditions i got error days is not defined

Comment: so.. what you can do is to make the default of Annual, ex you can make annual to 0 if you cannot find it.. so you can do const annual = res.find(o => (o.employees_id===resultArr[i]) && (o.leaves_type==="Annual")),and then you can do dataset.Annual=annual ? annual.days : 0;